# Python - Writing from a text file to a SQL database table

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes the metadata of photos in a directory. As of now the output of this script goes into a text file in a table. I have a SQL database table where I would like to write this to that table.

I have it set up where I can access the database table.

I would like to know how to write from the text file to the SQL table.

Here is the script:

```
import json
import pathlib
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import os
import os.path
import PIL
from pandas import json_normalize
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 384000000

rootdir = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics"

newfile = newfile = open('meta.txt', 'w')
newfile.write("Filename                        |File Size(In Bytes)            |File Type                   |Image DPI                    |Image Height                  |Image Width                 |Image Format                |Image Mode                  |Image Frames                |\n")
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    try:
        # read the image data using PIL
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

        # extract other basic metadata
        info_dict = {
            "Filename": os.path.basename(image.filename),
            "File Size": os.path.getsize(image.filename),
            "File Extension": pathlib.Path(image.filename).suffix,
            "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
            "Image Height": image.height,
            "Image Width": image.width,
            "Image Format": image.format,
            "Image Mode": image.mode,
            "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
        }

        line = ""
        for label, value in info_dict.items():
            line += f"|{str(value):<30} "
        line += " |"
        newfile.write(line + '\n')
    except:
        # read the image data using PIL
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

        # extract other basic metadata
        info_dict = {
            "Filename": os.path.basename(image.filename),
            "Image Height": image.height,
            "Image Width": image.width,
            "Image Format": image.format,
            "Image Mode": image.mode,
            "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
        }

        line = ""
        for label, value in info_dict.items():
            line += f"|{str(value):<30} "
        line += " |"
        newfile.write(line + '\n')
    
#Connect to the database
testDBCon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SRVISCDB,58837/testDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

#Choose what query to select a column from
query = "SELECT * FROM testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails;"
```

Here is the an example of the Text File:

```
Filename                        |File Size(In Bytes)            |File Type                   |Image DPI                    |Image Height                  |Image Width                 |Image Format                |Image Mode                  |Image Frames                |
|X00DL0027.jpg                  |30346                          |.jpg                           |(72, 72)                       |461                            |1280                           |JPEG                           |RGB                            |1                               |
|X01BJ0003.JPG                  |246029                         |.JPG                           |(72.0, 72.0)                   |400                            |600                            |JPEG                           |RGB                            |1                               |
|X01BJ0007.jpg                  |258407                         |.jpg                           |(72.0, 72.0)                   |400                            |600                            |JPEG                           |RGB                            |1                               |
|X01BJ0036.jpg                  |320987                         |.jpg                           |(72.0, 72.0)                   |400                            |600                            |JPEG                           |RGB                            |1                               |
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do i write from the text file to the sql tyable

Comment: Can you please share an example of the file?

Comment: You would use `sqlalchemy.insert` to insert a new row.  Do you know how your dict maps to the fields in the table?

Comment: No I am not too sure on how to use SQL and python. Hence why I am here. I know the table in the DB is already made.